# what is the reason behind iOS app getting more memory Impact

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, xcode9.2

I have an application in which my app's Memory impact crossed 438.7 Mb,
i checked with instruments but there was no  memory leaks ,i am surprised ,Is there any way to find out the reason behind it  ?

[image]

Comment: Use the "Allocations" tool in Instruments if "Leaks" doesn't show anything.  Look for objects that are bigger than you expect or objects that are created more often than you expect and not released.

Comment: Use real device with Instruments, simulator always does not shows correct values  (including for leaks)

Comment: when i tried to run in real device with Instruments the app is getting closed ,i am really stucked